# Removing similar columns pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a Pythonic way to remove similar columns in pandas. What I mean by that is columns that have a one-to-one correspondence. e.g.,

```
colA  colB  colC
A     C     B
A     G     B
C     K     D
C     G     D
```

Here I'd only like to retain `colA` and `colB` since knowing `colA` I always know `colC`.

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this to use `drop_duplicates` after having `factorize`d.  If there is a one to one correspondence, I know that the two columns will be factorized in the same way.  I'll then get the columns that make it back, and filter using those

```
cols = df.apply(lambda x: pd.factorize(x)[0]).T.drop_duplicates().index
df[cols]

  colA colB
0    A    C
1    A    G
2    C    K
3    C    G
```

Comment: The solution is correct but fails for large data frames as transpose is an expensive operation.